# Trying to pass bash variable with spaces

Tags: xml, bash, variables, sed

Can anyone help with this query. Currently attempting to pass a variable into xml using sed. This works fine with just the text, however its not picking up the variable within bash such as $1, $2 etc which will need to be inputted by the user.

EG:

`sed 's/<\/sProblemDesc>/'"anew test"'&/' create.xml`

successful output
 `<sProblemDesc>anew test</sProblemDesc>`

However when inserting a $1 variable between the anew test part, its either bringing back the literal name of the variable and not the data.

The user will be running the script as such

`./script.sh "enter stuff here" "enter more stuff" "21313122131"`

So I need to know how to get it to work with the variable but also take into consideration that I am having to use quotes to separate the variables..(if there is another way to do this let me know :D! )

Any queries let me know cheers

Update:
As requested the variable name is just variablename="$1"

I have tried removing the quotes as well just having =$1 does not seem to work with that either, so I am guessing its because when running the script (./script "stuff here" "etc" "etc" I am using quotes there but not sure how to get round it.

EG

Script

`variablename=$1`

`sed 's/<\/sProblemDesc>/'"$variablename"'&/' create.xml`

running the script

`./script "variablename here" "etc etc" "etc"`

XML is blank such as 
`<sProblemDesc></sProblemDesc>`

another example

`echo sed 's/<\/sActionDesc>/'"$variablename"'&/' create.xml`

returns the following which is not showing the variable name its just blank

`sed s/<\/sActionDesc>/&/ create.xml`

Cheers again

wingZero

Comment: Can you show how you used $1, $2?

Comment: I concur with the previous statement. I tried to recreate your script but it works just as you intended (from what I can infer).

Comment: Hi, the variable is variablename="$1"

Comment: @wingZero I just want to make sure you are prepending the variable name with a dollar sign sigil, e.g., `$variablename`. Edit: but not when setting the variable! (That is when you type `variablename=$1` is  correct but `"some string with variablename"` is not.)

Comment: I can't see the problem from your description. Please provide more information. Some simple examples would be helpful.

Comment: Hi,the variable name is just variablename=$1 as the user is entering the data when running the script. I did originally have it was variablename="$1" but I took it out because I thought the quotes were confusing it, I think when running the script ./ "enter $1 stuff here" it is causing the issue but if anyone can assist much appreciated.When running the script in bash its not entering anything into the XML due to having the variable where a new test is.EG: sed 's/<\/sProblemDesc>/'"$variablename"'&/' create.xml and then the user runs the script as ./script "enter stuff here" "etc" "etc"

Comment: So the expected output is `<sProblemDesc>enter suff here</sProblemDesc>` and it is not working?

Comment: Does your script lack a shebang line? Do you get the result you want if you run `sh ./myscript.sh stuff etc etc`?

Comment: Hi, when running that its not getting the stuff part and putting it to the xml file its just coming up blank, when it should insert the variable into the xml.

Comment: Another example of what is occuring `echo sed 's/<\/sActionDesc>/'"$variablename"'&/' create.xml`
`sed s/<\/sActionDesc>/&/ create.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some other issue, because this simple test works:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
myvar=$1
echo "<sProblemDesc></sProblemDesc>" | sed 's/<\/sProblemDesc>/'"$myvar"'&/'

$ ./test.sh "enter stuff here"
<sProblemDesc>enter stuff here</sProblemDesc>
```

What does your script do more that this?

Comment: Hi,Cheers for your comment as it has helped me to fix it!! Its due to the variable being after the event, like you said its working now!!Cheers very much :D!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
variablename=$1
echo ${variablename}

sed 's/<\/sProblemDesc>/'"${variablename}"'&/' create.xml
```

e.g. With the file create.xml as:

```
hello
<sProblemDesc></sProblemDesc>
```

this command:

```
./example.sh "here and here" foobar
```

produces:

```
here and here
hello
<sProblemDesc>here and here</sProblemDesc>
```

Comment: Hi,Cheers for your comment as it has helped me to fix it!! Its due to the variable being after the event, like you said its working now!!Cheers very much :D!!